# cloudera manager can only inspect one host at a time

Tags: docker, cloudera-cdh

I try to install CDH in docker offline.

I run cloudera-manager in one docker container and cloudera-scm-agent in another three docker container.

Each of the agent can connect to the cloudera-manager, but when I visit the web `http://xxx:7180/cmf/hardware/hosts`, I can only see one host at a time and the three host appear alternately.

anyone knows why?

the reason I found is the three container have same host-id, how could I change the host-id for each container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it,  it's in /var/lib/cloudera-scm/agent/uuid